# powerShell Set-acl strange error : there is not enough space on the disk

Tags: powershell, error-handling, active-directory, ldap, runtime-error

im working on a PS script that sets permissions to the active directory.
i've been working on this for a while now, and suddenly i get a strange error message when using the set-acl function.

**the error message is :**

```
Set-Acl : There is not enough space on disk
AT c:\users\apppki2\desktop\fimxxx.ps1:457 char:17
+   set-acl -aclobject $acl "${tmpPsDrive}:${targetDrive}"
+   ~~~~~

+Categoryinfo : notspecified : (cn=.....:string) [set-acl], adexception
+fullyqualifiederrorid : adprovider:setsecuritydescriptor:aderror,microsoft.powershell.commands.setaclcommand
```

i want to mention again, this code worked, and still working on a test enviroment.but not wherei really want it to work, and was working by now.

how can i investigate this issue further ? where cani get more leads or error details ?

thanks...

Comment: Please post the code, difficult to debug from an error message alone. `"${tmpPsDrive}:${targetDrive}"` looks like a physical path. I'm assuming you *have* checked to make sure the disk has space left?

Comment: @arco444 hi, this is a psDrive networkpath to a domain controller. has free space, i also tryed to add permissions manually on the dc,and it worked fine.

Comment: @DavidGidony Do you have any Read-Only Domain Controllers in your AD domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after freeing up space on the dc, i still kept getting this error massages.
after verifing credentials and user right for a few hours, i just hit the reset button on the dc machine, and pooof, everything got back to normal, working perfect.

probably some sort of caching on the dc side, i still didnt figure out how i could fix that without the restart.

works for now, im happy!

thank y'all